# Implement a singly linked list in java without classes

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I was solving the question : https://www.codingninjas.com/studio/problems/introduction-to-linked-list_8144737?utm_source=striver&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=a_zcoursetuf&leftPanelTab=0
and on implementing the code i got the error saying "Duplicate class name : Node". Below is the code which I wrote for the same :

```
 class Node {
 public static int data;
 public static  Node next;

 Node()
 {
     this.data = 0;
     this.next = null;
 }

 Node(int data)
 {
     this.data = data;
     this.next = null;
 }

 Node(int data, Node next)
 {
     this.data = data;
     this.next = next;
 }
 };



class implement {
 public static  Node head;
 static Node addatend(int value){
     Node temp=head;
     Node add= new Node(value);
     if(head==null){
        head=add;
     }
     else{
         while(temp.next!=null){
             temp=temp.next;
         }
         temp.next=add;
     }
     return head;
}



public class Solution {
 public static Node constructLL(int []arr) {
    // Write your code here
    Node ans=null;
    implement z = new implement ();
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        int t=arr[i];
       ans= z.addatend(t);

    }
    return ans;
}
}
```

Can anyone point to the error in the code?

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: can you run your code in the link provide in the question and then run it ?

Comment: Why is everything declared as `static`?

Comment: I have changed the codebase of the question , also should I remove the static keyword from every variable/method ?

Comment: You don't have to implement `Node` yourself. It's already there in their environment.

Comment: the node class was given in the question , I just created additional class to implement the function addatend

Comment: can I solve the problem through the code which i wrote ?

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone my code ran , but unfortunately showed TLE in one test case .
Cheers !!

Answer (score 2):

Use two pointers instead.

```
public static Node constructLL(int[] arr) {
    Node head = null;
    Node end = null;
    for (int a : arr) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node(a);
            end = head;
        }
        else {
            end.next = new Node(a);
            end = end.next;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

Alternative solution - traverse array from end and insert to the list at the front:

```
public static Node constructLL(int[] arr) {
    Node head = null;
    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        Node temp = new Node(arr[i]);
        temp.next = head;
        head = temp;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: @user85421, thanks, I edited my answer to include this alternative solution.